# Sending extra parameters except form fields

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Good day, everyone. I 'm writing a project based on Thymeleaf and I stuck with such a problem. Well I have a form with the help of which search will be implemented.

```
 <form method="get" th:action="@{/participants/search}">

     ...

    <button id="searchButton" class="btn btn-default"                                    
            th:onclick="|sendSearchRequest(this.form, 0, ${selectedPageSize})|">Search</button>
 <form>
```

I have some inputs and selects inside this form. But also I need to send some pageSize (amount of elements to show) and currentPage index to work with Pageable object on back-end. Well I tried to do smth like that:

```
 function sendSearchRequest(form, currentPage, pageSize) {
    form.action = '/participants/search/' + getSearchParams(currentPage,pageSize);
    form.submit();
 }
```

And in getSearchParams(...) method I wanted to grab all parameters from form + add info about currentPage and pageSize.

```
  function getSearchParams(currentPage, pageSize) {
     var paramString = '?page=' + currentPage + '&size=' + pageSize;
     Array.from($("#searchForm").find(":input").not(":button"))
       .forEach(function (child) {
     paramString += "&" + child.name + "=" + child.value;
    });
    return paramString;
  }
```

Well the problem is that I can't pass additional page parameters to my request. Only fields from the form can be passed. In my request I can only this:

```
  ...participants/search/?searchParam=c&applicationType=&status=all
```

So as you can see there no page parameters, but I thought it would be something like that:

```
participants/search/? 
  page=0&size=20&searchParam=c&applicationType=&status=all
```

By the way I've also tried:

```
 location.replace('/participants/search/' + getSearchParams(currentPage, pageSize))
```

But the result was unsuccessful either.

Would you suggest any solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

Please use hidden input type fields to send additional request parameter with a form submission like below :

```
<form method="get" th:action="@{/participants/search}">
        ...
    <input value="1" type="hidden" name="page">
    <input value="10" type="hidden" name="size">

    <button id="searchButton" class="btn btn-default" th:onclick="|sendSearchRequest(this.form, 0, ${selectedPageSize})|">Search</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can try using an ajax request, simple store the additional information as a json object and pass it to your controller.

    **Json data**

    dataset = {

      "into" : "value1"
      "into2" : "value2"
    }

Ajax request would look like this;

   $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                accept: "text/html",
                //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/yoururl/"",
                data: ({
                    "data": dataset


                }),
                success: function() {
                   console.log("done");
                }

            });
```